# PySpark df.na.drop() vs. df.dropna()

Tags: dataframe, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to remove rows from my PySpark df where there are null values in any of the columns, but it is taking a really long time to run when using `df.dropna()`. Is there any benefit performance wise to using `df.na.drop()` instead?

I like using `df.dropna()` because I can specify which columns to look for null values, but I am finding that it is still very slow (the data frame has millions of rows, so this could be why)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [spark official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna), `DataFrame.dropna()` and `DataFrameNaFunctions.drop()` are aliases of each other. So theoretically their efficiency should be equivalent.

In addition, [df.na.drop()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.drop.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.drop) can also specify a subset.